# Задача на Py.CheckiO на Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, замена, tuple

Всем добрый день, сижу на py.checkio, изучаю python 3. Сейчас попалась задача, где нужно все слова right заменить на left. Решил пойти наверное сложным путём и решил перебирать куча циклов. Короче вот мой код:

```
   def left_join(phrases: tuple) -> str:
    result_str = ''
    for ch in phrases:
        res_ch = str(ch).split(' ')
        length = len(res_ch)
        for char in res_ch:
            if 'right' in str(char):
                start = str(char).find('right')
                end = start + len('right')
                result = str(char)[:start] + 'left' + str(char)[end:]
                if length > 1:
                    result_str += result + ' '
                    length -= 1
                else:
                    if len(phrases) == 1:
                        result_str += result
                    else:
                        result_str += result + ','
            else:
                if char == phrases[-1]:
                    result_str += str(char)
                else:
                    result_str += str(char) + ','
    return result_str
```

Проблема начинаеться, когда он пытаеться автоматически подставить кортеж ("lorem","ipsum","dolor","sit","amet","consectetuer","adipiscing","elit","aenean","commodo","ligula","eget","dolor","aenean","massa","cum","sociis","natoque","penatibus","et","magnis","dis","parturient","montes","nascetur","ridiculus","mus","donec","quam","felis","ultricies","nec","pellentesque","eu","pretium","quis","sem","nulla","consequat","massa","quis").

Он выдает слова

"quis"

и

"sem"

почему-то как одно целое, то есть 'quissem'.

Не понимаю почему, пытался уже и на визуализаторах смотреть и в разных idle, не понимаю почему он склеивает именно эти строки

Comment: Приведите пример, какой должен быть результат для приведенных входных данных.

Comment: text.replace('right', 'left')

Comment: @insolor для данного кортежа должен быть такой же выход. Там же нет ни одного слова right, соответсвенно ничего не должно меняться, но вот те два слова что я написал, почему то склеиваються в один елемент

Comment: @Jack_oS спасибо, переписал код с replace и все супер заработало)

Comment: @Alexseusik нужно в вопросе указывать все данные, чтобы не нужно было догадываться что должно быть на выходе.

Answer (score 1):

```
if char == phrases[-1]:           # при char == "quis"
    result_str += str(char)       # элементы склеиваются
else:
    result_str += str(char) + ',' # иначе разделяются запятой
```

Вот здесь и происходит ваша склейка, поскольку последний элемент кортежа, т.е. `phrases[-1]` у вас `"quis"` и поэтому на элементе `"quis"` который перед элементом `"sem"` выполняется этот `if` и элементы не разделяются запятой, в отличие от всех остальных проходов цикла по элементам кортежа.